# Create Sharepoint View sorted by fixed values across several columns

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I'm new to SharePoint 2013 and working on a list for projects that our department has. Each project may have 1 to 6 contributors (each with a column in the list; primary, secondary, back up etc...) The columns are dropdowns of all team members we have.

Is there a way to sort the list by the name of each team member, which will show all projects he/she is involved with?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter each column by every value this column has.

Just click in the title name and select the value you want to filter.

[image]

Comment: thanks @Divisix - I'm trying your suggestion above. But I'm not getting the result I need which is the list sorted by the individual then the projects where he/she is a primary, secondary and back-up...

Comment: With a custom view you also can sort the results by different columns... Maybe this solution is good for you...

Comment: I was able to create a view with multiple filters, but it will only apply to 1 person, and show all projects that person is involved with. Anyone out there with other ideas/suggestions?